# Can't goto the question I already answered and was accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, questions, deleted-questions

I saw my reputation dropping by some points. When I hover over my name and see my recent questions/answers. I see a 4 questions. Out of those 4 I am not able goto the 3rd question. Basically there is no hyperlink in there. What s the reason for this.It shows -15 reps for me but if this question is deleted then I should have not been subtracted by -15.

Attached is the screen shot I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can delete questions for which answer is posted and accepted.

Comment: If the question is bad or inappropriate enough it can be deleted for sure. No matter its status. And as a consequence, you will lose the rep you've earned. Not a bug. (Note: I don't know what happened to the question and why)

Comment: On your reputation tab, it is likely this will be lumped into a "user was removed" line item. Do you see this on your reputation tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user that asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11776904/50776) was destroyed.  This causes the deletion of *all* of that users content, answers *and* questions.  Because the question you answered was one of this user's posts, your answer was deleted along with it.

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

I'd undelete it, but the question is incredibly localized and won't benefit anyone else on the site.

Comment: But would happen to my reps.

Comment: @refhat you won't get that back, unfortunately, as you can't earn rep from deleted questions that are less than six months old.

Answer (score 3):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776904/website-css-issue-on-different-systems) (10k only link) in question was deleted yesterday. And because there is no name next to message I think the user account is deleted from the system.

Comment: where did you got the link to this question

Comment: @refhat I've googled the title

Comment: hmm, The first link results in the correct result, but unfortunately a broken  link

Comment: @refhat The link is "broken" because only users with 10k rep can see deleted questions.

Comment: I mean first link from google results.

Answer (score 1):

When a question is deleted, the answer that was accepted is automatically unaccepted, and you lose the reputation you gain from your answer. I am not sure this happens with the reputation gained from having your answer accepted, when the answer is older than X days, though.

This is what happened in your case: There isn't any link to the question because the question was deleted, and you cannot see deleted questions. If you were a 10K user, you could see deleted questions for which you are given the link.